# Wp8 map api vs Android Map api

Tags: android, google-maps, windows-phone-8

Hi I want to build an application (wp8 and android version) using google map.

Well for android no problem, seems have no request limit at all, but for wp8 I'd like to use also google map, because bing limit is 50000 req/day, so Is there an api, or there's a way to use an api for NET which have no limitation like android one?

p.s.

I've seen javascript library but isn't good fit I wan't to avoid limitation... tanks

Comment: what are you trying to do that you are facing a 50,000 limit?

Comment: Hi first I don't understant if 50000 is for application or ip, then I have a youtube app that would show near you where are video, so you can zoom or pan around the world... so I'm scare that limit is easy to beat :)

Comment: If you are using WP8 then use the new [Map API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045(v=vs.105).aspx). If just showing a map with pushpins for known locations there is no limit.

Comment: are you shure??????? if so post the answer :)

Comment: seem not really, seem that display map is a transaction

Comment: Are you using the new Nokia Maps with WP8 or the Bing Maps with WP7? According to the [terms of use](http://cmsresources.windowsphone.com/devcenter/en-us/legal/MSFT_Mapping_API_Terms.pdf) the only restriction is on Geocoding. It is also not mentioned on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_terms) or [Nokia](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!guide-to-the-maps.html) documentation.

Comment: I dunno, bing map I hope, but it's really interesting... because I've wrote to microsoft and the answer (for bing maps) is that every time you ask a map is billable transaction (really weird), can U tell me more, have you used? I dunno how insert into my project wp8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are focusing on Windows Phone 8 then you will not be using the Bing maps SDK and therefore do not need a Bing key. You should use the new Nokia Maps control located under the Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls namespace. This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) post offers a step by step guide to creating an app with the new Map control.

Comment: thanks, I dunno before now nokia map (developer point of view), bytheway you know limit? or other things?

Comment: Nokia maps does not have a request limit. Another benefit is the user can download maps that can be used across all apps. This removes the need to ping the server for map images

Comment: are u really really shure? I hope :)